# Difference between "jail" and "prison" in German

Tags: english-to-german, legal-terminology

In some English-speaking countries, there is a difference between the words *prison* and *jail, jail* being where you are placed prior to a conviction, *prison* being where you are held afterwards. In German, the word *Gefängnis* seems to be used interchangeably as does the more slang word *Knast* (at least Google translate and my dictionary both suggest this).

So my question is, is there a more specific word like *jail* in German?

Comment: _"jail being where you are placed prior to a conviction"_ That would be _Untersuchungsgefängnis_ in German.

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @infinitezero I explained a bit why I didn't wrote that as an answer [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53622/difference-between-jail-and-prison-in-german#comment130515_53623)

Comment: The difference in meaning between the words “jail” and “prison” that you describe is, as far as I know, only in North American usage.

Comment: "*jail* being where you are placed prior to a conviction, *prison* being where you are held afterwards" – That is not an accurate description of the difference. You can also be placed in jail *after* a conviction. In particular, sentences for *misdemeanors* up to one year will be served in jail, sentences for *felonies* more than one year will be served in prison. Also, you will be placed in jail after being sentenced before being transported to a prison.

Comment: @CarstenS Even in North America, "jail" and "prison" are considered synonymous by most people. I doubt you'd find one in five people outside the legal system who'd be familiar with the distinction.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The building is the same in both cases. It is called *»Gefängnis«* as you already know. But the kind of residence has different names:

- **Untersuchungshaft** or **U-Haft**
  *imprisonment on remand*
  When you are under suspicion, but not yet convicted
  (verb "untersuchen" = "to investigate")
- **Strafhaft**
  *imprisonment for sentence*
  When you are validly convicted
  (verb "strafen" = to punish)

In both cases you are a *»Häftling«* (prisoner, inmate). If you are in *Untersuchungshaft,* you are a *»Untersuchungshäftling«* or *»U-Häftling«*. If you are convinced, you are a *»Strafhäftling«* or *»Sträfling«.*

There are *Gefängnisse* where both kinds of *Häftlinge* are locked-in. Only a few buildings are only for long-time inmates, i.e. only for *Sträflinge*. But the majority of *Gefängnisse* are mixed.

There are also *»Hafträume«* (also: *»Zellen«*) (cells) in police stations, but inmates may only stay there for one day before they will be transported to a *Gefängnis*. Those buildings are not called *Gefängnis,* but *Polizeistation* or *Wachstube.* Their main purpose is to be a police station, i.e. a place where police officers have their offices.

Comment: I also thought that the difference in German more relates to the kind of _"Haft"_, than the specific kind of building (that's why I didn't wrote an answer). There are more though. _Gewahrsam_, _Abschiebehaft_, etc.

Comment: For completeness you could also mention "Ausnüchterungszelle"

Comment: **Gewahrsam** matches *jail* best, as the police may take you into *Gewahrsam* without approval from a judge. That's what a *jail* is in the US AFAIK. Doesn't have to be a building, a vehicle meant for detention suffices.

Comment: @Janka: I think "Gewahrsam" is more like "lockup" or a "holding cell" than "jail". The  main differences between *jail* and *prison* are basically that a) jails are run by the city or county whereas prisons are run by the state or federal government, b) jail has a higher turnover (more inmates leaving and arriving), c) jail has shorter stays (sentences for misdemeanors up to one year are served in jail, sentences for felonies longer than year are served in prison). This distinction doesn't really exist in Germany, AFAIK, there are no special facilities for someone convicted of a "Vergehen".

Comment: @Janka: Den Begriff »Gewahrsam« kenne ich eigentlich nur aus dem Sachen-Recht. Wenn man eine Sache (z.B. einen Ball) in Gewahrsam hat, dann verfügt man tatsächlich physisch über diese Sache. Im österreichischen Recht gibt es aber auch die Festnahme. Dabei wird eine Person durch physische Maßnahmen (fesseln, einsperren) an der Flucht gehindert. Das ist eine Form der Freiheitsberaubung, zu der aber jede Person berechtigt ist, wenn sie daraufhin unverzüglich die Polizei verständigt, und dann plausibel machen kann, dass sie die festgenommene Person dringend einer Straftat verdächtigt.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Mit deutschem Recht kenne ich mich nicht aus. Im Österreichischen Strafrecht gibt es eine Unterscheidung zwischen *Vergehen* und *Verbrechen*, und ich vermute, das wird in Deutschland ähnlich sein: Ein Vergehen ist eine Straftat, die mit maximal 3 Jahren Haft bedroht ist. Ein Verbrechen ist eine Straftat, für die laut StGB mehr als 3 Jahre Haft verhängt werden können. Z.B.: Diebstahl (Kaugummi im Supermarkt): 0 bis 6 Monate = Vergehen. Raub (Androhung von Gewalt um sich eine Sache anzueignen): 1 bis 10 Jahre Haft = Verbrechen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Dieselbe Unterscheidung gibt es im deutschen Strafrecht auch, wobei die Grenze bei einem Jahr liegt. Es gibt aber, im Gegensatz zum US-Strafvollzug und der Unterscheidung dort zwischen *jail* und *prison* meines Wissens keine getrennten Anstalten für Insassen, die eines Verbrechens oder eines Vergehens verurteilt wurden. Beide verbüßen ihre Strafe im Gefängnis.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Richtig: Verbrecher und "Vergeher" sitzen gemeinsam in derselben Zelle. Getrennt wird nur zwischen U-Häftlingen und Sträflingen. Die sitzen nicht in gemeinsam in denselben Zellen, wohl aber im selben Gebäude.

Comment: looks like we need to specify the jurisdiction here. Because for U-Haft you need (in Germany) strong reasons like "danger of flight" => detention, simple Gewahrsam (can be custody) is made by police for simple stuff like short fist fight and refuse to stop.

Comment: You can also be imprisoned if you won't pay a *Bussgeld* for an *Ordnungswidrigkeit*; it's called *Erzwingungshaft*. If you do not bear witness in a court case you can be taken in *Beugehaft*. In both cases you are not charged with any criminal offense (*Ordnungswidrigkeit* is not a criminal offense); nevertheless you'll likely be held in the same facility as the murderers.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: In Österreich gibt es genau drei Gründe um eine verdächtigte, aber noch nicht rechtskräftig verurteilte Person zu inhaftieren: Fluchtgefahr (es besteht Grund zur Annahme, dass sich die Person dem Zugriff der Behörden entziehen möchte), Wiederbegehungsgefahr (es wird befürchtet dass die Person eine weitere Straftat begehen möchte) und Verdunkelungsgefahr (Befürchtung, dass die Person die Ermittlungen der Behörde vereiteln möchte). Solange einer dieser Gründe vorliegt, und solange kein Urteil vorliegt, kann die U-Haft beliebig lange verlängert werden, manchmal auch mehrere Jahre...

Comment: ... Wenn keiner dieser Haftgründe vorliegt, und wenn es kein rechtskräftiges Urteil gibt, darf man maximal 48 Stunden lang festgehalten werden. Möglicherweise heißt diese Frist in Deutschland »Gewahrsam«. In Österreich ist das eine »Festnahme.«

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Auch dazu eine Ergänzung zum Österreichischen Recht: In Österreich gibt es denBegriff »Bußgeld« nicht. Wenn man von einem Organ der Exekutive (also von einem Polizisten) wegen einer Verwaltungsübertretung (z.B. Geschwindigkeitsübertretung beim Autofahren) eine Strafe zu zahlen hat heißt diese Straße in Ö: »Organstrafmandat.« Wenn aber ein Gericht eine Geldstrafe verhängt, bei deren Nichtbezahlung eine Ersatzhaftstrafe verhängt wird, dann spricht man von »Taggeld« (weil man sich tageweise von der Freiheitsstrafe freikaufen kann).

Comment: @infinitezero: Sorry, ich habe deinen Kommentar erst jetzt bemerkt. Zumindest in Österreich gibt es keine dezidierten *Ausnüchterungszellen.* Es gibt nur die ganz normalen Hafträume der Polizeistationen, die ich in meiner Antwort bereits erwähnt habe. Wenn jemand randaliert, wird er dort eingesperrt, und zwar völlig unabhängig von seinem Alkoholspiegel. Wenn einer übermäßig alkoholisiert ist, ist das eher ein Fall für die Rettung, die ihn in ein Spital bringt. Dort gibt es für diese Herrschaften aber auch keine Zellen, sondern meist nur Liegen am Gang.